# Running total of a Measure

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax, measure

i'm looking to create a running total of a MEASURE (here name Open vs Closed). I have all my colums correct except the last one "Total Open".
Anybody knows a measure to have this as a running total of the Open vs Closed column ?

```
WeekIndex |Open Incidents | Closed Incidents | Open vs Closed | Total Open
1         | 5             | 0                | +5             | 5
2         | 4             | 5                | -1             | 4
3         | 2             | 0                | +2             | 6
4         | 3             | 3                | +0             | 6
5         | 10            | 12               | -2             | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculated column using the `EARLIER` function can do in this case:

```
Total Open = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Open vs Closed]),
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[WeekIndex] <= EARLIER('Table'[WeekIndex])
    )
)
```

Results:

[image: results]

---

Updated:

The following measure should work in this case. The `ALL` function is needed to ignore the row level context when it's put in the table:

```
Total Open Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    [Open vs Closed Measure],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[WeekIndex] <= MAX('Table'[WeekIndex])
    )
)
```

[image: results2]

---

Second update:

Given the weird case that all columns are measures:

```
Total Open Measure = 
VAR CurrentIndex = [Index]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Open vs Closed Measure],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        [Index] <= CurrentIndex
    )
)
```

[image: results3]

---

Third Update:

I can only come up with a way using the `MonthIndex`. I think the reason of that extra `6` is due to the way you calculate `Incidents Closed`. Anyways I fix it by adding `'Calendar'[MonthIndex] >= 1` to the filter:

```
Total Open Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    [Open vs Closed],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[MonthIndex] >= 1 &&
        'Calendar'[MonthIndex] <= MAX('Calendar'[MonthIndex])
    )
)
```

To filter out the rows without incidents I added a visual level filter on the `Index` measure:

[image: results4]

Comment: Hi, problem is that i don't use a table for this but just a calculated field. The Open vs Closed is a calculated field

Comment: I'm not quite getting it. My `Open vs Closed = 'Table'[Open Incidents] - 'Table'[Closed Incidents]` is a calculated column as well.

Comment: your Open vs Closed is a colomn in the "Table" table. I don't have a Open vs Closed Column in my table. my Open vs Closed is a measure

`Open Incidents = COUNTA(Incident[Incident ID])`

`Closed Incints = CALCULATE([Incidenten geopend];USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date];Incident[Datum gereed]))`
`Open vs. Closed =[Open Incidents]-[Closed incidents]`

Comment: That's because in your question you said "i'm looking to create a running total of a `calculated column` (here name Open vs Closed)." ..

Comment: So your `Open vs Closed` is a measure instead of a calculated column?

Comment: Correct, sorry for the mislead :/ I adjusted the question and title

Comment: Thx, will try it tomorrow. Now relax :) Will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Something doesn't work. i get the message Column WeekIndex in table incident is not found or can't be used in this expression. I am sure the index column is there.

WeekIndex is a measure too. It takes the calculated Column WeekIndex from my Calendar table like this `IF([Incidenten geopend]<>0;'Calendar'[Gemiddelde van Maand Index];BLANK())` This prevents my Slider which contains months to have values for emty fields where otherwise only an index is displayed

Comment: Why would you want all "columns" in measures in the first place..? Can you provide the .pbix or [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can work on without digging out the details bit by bit?

Comment: I'll post an example

Comment: Here an example of the excel file, i'm not using power BI
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BygKmytZVBjib25RazBQejJ4R3c

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye Answers updated, with `Index` being a measure. I don't have PowerPivot so that's the best I can achieve.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get values but not the correct ones. I will try to recreate it in Power Bi and post it

Comment: Here my power BI link. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BygKmytZVBjiNjZHRFJsWElyZ2c

I posted one earlier but now it's complete.

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye Answers updated. I hope it should at least work perfectly in Power BI.

Comment: Genius !! Works both in excel as in Power Bi !! Thanks a lot for all the effort.