# Rolling Sum using two columns in Power BI

Tags: sum, powerbi, multiple-columns, dax

I've two columns containing sales from last year and this year and a data column with the number of weeks we are in. I want to calculate a yearly rolling sum in a new column from the week we are in back in the past till that same week.

In my example if i'm in week 2 this year my rolling sum will be sum all the values of sales last year from week 2 til week 52 plus sales from this year until week 2 including!!

Here's an example in excel of what my table and results would look like:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891153/running-total-of-a-measure and this https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/computing-running-totals-in-dax/

Comment: @AngeloCanepa the problem is that i don't have the sales in the same column they are both in two sperate columns that's why i'm struggling ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data look like this

```
Table
+------+----------+-------+
| week | sales_ly | sales |
+------+----------+-------+
| 1    | 65       | 100   |
+------+----------+-------+
| 2    | 93       | 130   |
+------+----------+-------+
| 3    | 83       | 134   |
+------+----------+-------+
| 4    | 3083     | 59    |
+------+----------+-------+
| 5    | 30984    | 39    |
+------+----------+-------+
| 6    | 38       | 580   |
+------+----------+-------+
| 7    | 28       | 94    |
+------+----------+-------+
| 8    | 48       | 93    |
+------+----------+-------+
| 9    | 24       | 984   |
+------+----------+-------+
| 10   | 49       | 95    |
+------+----------+-------+
```

You need to create two cumulatives and sum them in the same measure.

```
Rolling Sum = 

VAR CurrentYearCumulative = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[sales]),
        FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Table'),'Table'[week] <= MAX('Table'[week] ) )
        )

VAR LastYearCumulative = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[sales_ly]),
        FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Table'),'Table'[week] >= MAX('Table'[week]) )
        )

RETURN

CurrentYearCumulative + LastYearCumulative
```

The output

[image]

Comment: sales are the sales for this year ?

Comment: @hurop yes. `sales` is for this year.

Comment: Can you please explain why you used max ?

Comment: Please refer to the link shared earlier, in there they explain in detail how it works. I've only replicated their logics.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get the chance to test it but the formula is not what I want ... the results are wrong ..

Comment: if you look at my example if i'm in this year week 2 my rolling sum will be sum all the values of sales last year from week 2 til week 52 plus sales from this year until week 2 including ... that's what i'm trying to do ...

Comment: @hurop I've edited my answer to reflect your original requirement. The output is the same as the one outlined in your question. The change was modifying the variable `LastYearCumulative`  in the filter statement from `<=` to `>=`